# How to create a json array string from a string of comma separated values?

Tags: arrays, json, shell

I have a string of some comma separated values.

e.g. - `"Paris,Mumbai,London,Tokyo,Boston"`

Now what I need is a string like this:

```
"["Paris","Mumbai","London","Tokyo","Boston"]"
```

I am able to create an array of strings using IFS. But not able to create the above mentioned json array 
string that I need. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`"["Paris","Mumbai","London","Tokyo","Boston"]"` not is a well formed Json.

This is the correct format.

`["Paris","Mumbai","London","Tokyo","Boston"]`

It is ugly... I know:

```
echo "Paris,Mumbai,London,Tokyo,Boston" | perl -p -e "s/,/\",\"/g" | sed 's/^/[\"/g' | sed 's/$/\"]/g'
```

This returns:

```
["Paris","Mumbai","London","Tokyo","Boston"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you, assuming bash 4.4+:

```
$ INPUT_CITIES="Paris,Mumbai,London,Tokyo,Boston"
$ mapfile -td , cities < <(printf "%s" "$INPUT_CITIES")
$ jo -a "${cities[@]}"
["Paris","Mumbai","London","Tokyo","Boston"]
```

This assumes you have https://github.com/jpmens/jo installed.